# Hook IntelliSense completion list

Tags: hook, intellisense, visual-studio-extensions

is it possible to hook the completion list show function?

I mainly want to create an extension that when a completion list is shown, get the first suggestion and store it in a file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out, that it's possible to get the suggestion list using [complex commands API](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensionAPI/vscode-api-commands).

The command name is: `vscode.executeCompletionItemProvider` and we can can call it using `vscode.commands.executeCommand`

```
// the Position object gives you the line and character where the cursor is
const position = editor.selection.active;

// Get document Uri
const docUri = vscode.window.activeTextEditor.document.uri;

completionList = vscode.commands.executeCommand(
   'vscode.executeCompletionItemProvider',
    docUri,
    position
)
```